# Is there a way to tell if user is the organization admin in azure devops extension api

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

Using the [Azure Devops Extension API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api/tree/master/src) in an extension I'm building and wondering if there is an API available to tell if the current user is the organization admin so that we can hide/show different options for that user(s). Or is there another API that I can hit from my extension to get some extended details about the current user rather than what comes back with `SDK.getUser()`

Comment: Please have a look the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get PCA members via the API below, and check whether the current user in PCA:

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0